# Different text width in the same filetype in vim

Tags: vim

I am editing my markdown files which contain some code examples ([like here](http://svenduplic.com/2012/12/22/how-i-setup-my-rails-app.html)). Is there any way to tell vim, when it is editing markdown files, to set textwidth=80 to everything except where I keep my code syntax? So for example:

```
Here is a text within a markdown file // textwidth=80

    puts 'Hello World' // textwidth is not specified
```

Comment: `puts 'Hello World'` is code in Markdown?

Comment: yup, but it is indented 4 spaces, and markdown recognises that as code so it uses special syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to simply set `tw` option to meet your requirement. However I came up with a function, it could do what you want:

```
function! WrapMD()
   let x=&tw
   let &tw=80
   normal! gqq
   let &tw=x
endfunction
```

this function just does format with `tw=80` on current line, after that restores your original `tw` setting.

You can source the function (or put it in your vimrc), and then do:

```
:v/\v^( {4}|\t)/call WrapMD()
```

at any time when you want to format your MD text.

You could also create a mapping for that or put it in a `autocmd` on event `BufWritePre`.

Here I made a gif when I test the function:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `'textwidth'` setting dynamically with an `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI <buffer> let &textwidth = (getline('.') =~# '^    ' ? 0 : 80)
```

This checks for Markdown code (indented by 4 spaces), and then clears the textwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use pandoc to tidy up markdown: `pandoc -t markdown` will wrap markdown, but not code blocks. It also nicely tidies up lists and block quotes. The vim-pandoc plugin sets `'equalprg'` to `pandoc -t markdown --reference-links`.